Unable to boot into new Ubuntu installation
I’ve installed Ubuntu 24.10 on an old laptop, however, when I boot it back up, the boot drive cannot be found.
After some messing around with bios settings and reinstalling, I now get to Grub and have the options “Try or install Ubuntu”, “Ubuntu (safe graphics)”, “Boot from next volume” and “UEFI Firmware Settings”.
When selecting Boot From Next Volume, I get the following:
No bootable devices found
Initially, when I first installed Ubuntu, then booted back up, I was getting the following error:
PXE-E61 media test failure, check cable
Can anyone advise what I need to do, to get Ubuntu running?
My knowledge of boot loaders is somewhat basic, although I’m fine with using Terminal commands.
Thanks in advance.

I had the same issue. I had to go through the install process 3 times. After the 3rd time, my bios just magically saw the the installed OS.

A correctly-done install of Ubuntu does not have a "Try or Install Ubuntu" option. Only the installer has it. This suggests that you did not correctly install Ubuntu. Start your install over from the very beginning: Making the LiveUSB. Follow the instructions.

PXE is network boot. That is one of the first things I run off in UEFI settings. I do not want UEFI going out to network.  That often is a last default boot option or you have other boot issues. Also how you installed UEFI or very old BIOS is then how you must set UEFI/BIOS settings to boot. Systems since about 2012 are UEFI and should have gpt partitioning. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary reportUse often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I'm running 24.04 on an old (2010) Dell Inspiron 1545. BIOS is set to: NIC=enabled @ 'LAN with PXE boot' AND SATA set to: 'SATA is configured for AHCI mode'. As I understand it, this is 'legacy-boot'... My grub is MBR located inside SDA6, which is my boot partition with 24.04. NO separate grub partition (ie:FAT32/EFI)... So if you're obliged to use legacy boot due to an older BIOS, those should be the correct BIOS settings and will likely fix any BIOS/Boot issues. However, it sounds like you're booting with the USB install medium plugged-in and your BIOS is set to boot from the USB. As mentioned by earlier answer, "Try or Install Ubuntu" is only seen on the installation 'post-boot' screen. Sounds like you need to do a fresh install. I highly recommend Balena Etcher to burn the ISO-- see: https://etcher.balena.io/#download-etcher  --  Using a 16gb USB is best. I tried two other 'burners' and they both failed to boot to "Try or Install Ubuntu" screen. Balena Etcher also saves settings for reboots of live session. After booting the Ubuntu 24.04.1 install-USB, make sure you choose 'Erase disk and Install Ubuntu 24.04' when prompted. Hope this helps.
